# listings - use different style for normal comments /* and doxygen comments /**

Tags: listings, highlighting, comments

listings package allows setting basicstyle, keywordstyle, identifierstyle,
commentstyle, stringstyle. Is it possible to set different style for comments that start from `/**` not just `/*`?

To make my question more clear. Assume I have set environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{beramono}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{beraserif}

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{
language=C++,
basicstyle=\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont,
keywordstyle=\bfseries, 
identifierstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\fontfamily{fve}\selectfont\color{olive}, 
stringstyle=\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont,
frame=single,showstringspaces=false,columns=flexible} }
{}
```

and I have the following code

```
\begin{document}
\begin{MyCode}
/*
 Multi-line 
 non-Doxygen comments
*/
#include <iostream>

/** Single-line Doxygen comment */
class MyClass {
private: 
  int value; /**< After member Doxygen comment */
public:
  /** 
   * Multi-line Doxygen comment
   * @param int x new value
   * @return bool operation success
   */
  bool setValue(int x /**< [in] also Doxygen */) {
    this->value = x; /* non-Doxygen comment */
    std::cout << "I'm setting value " << x << std::endl;
    /* Single line non-Doxygen comment */
    return true;
  }  
};
\end{MyCode}
\end{document}
```

There are mixed:

- usual comments starting with `/*`
- Doxygen (javadoc) comments starting with `/**`

`/**` itself starts with `/*` so all comments are formatted according to

```
commentstyle=\fontfamily{fve}\selectfont\color{olive},
```

Is it possible to distinguish between those comments and set another style for `/**` comments? For example color them red not olive.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listings` package allows for multiple comment delimiters, but only one comment style. However, you can get around this limitation by using the `moredelim` key. In your particular example, you could write something like

```
moredelim = [s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/}
```

and the style used for "comments" delimited by `\**` and `*\` will be different to that used for comments delimited by `/*` and `*/`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
  {\lstset{
    language         = C++,
    basicstyle       = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle     = \bfseries,
    identifierstyle  = \color{blue},
    commentstyle     = \color{olive},
    moredelim        = [s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/},
    stringstyle      = \color{magenta},
    frame            = single,
    showstringspaces = false,
    columns          = flexible}
  }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyCode}
/*
 Multi-line
 non-Doxygen comments
*/
#include <iostream>

/** Single-line Doxygen comment */
class MyClass {
private:
  int value; /**< After member Doxygen comment */
public:
  /**
   * Multi-line Doxygen comment
   * @param int x new value
   * @return bool operation success
   */
  bool setValue(int x /**< [in] also Doxygen */) {
    this->value = x; /* non-Doxygen comment */
    std::cout << "I'm setting value " << x << std::endl;
    /* Single line non-Doxygen comment */
    return true;
  }
};
\end{MyCode}

\end{document}
```