# listings - highlighting additional keywords inside own delimiters (like Doxygen annotations)

Tags: listings, highlighting

According to [listings - use different style for normal comments /* and doxygen comments /**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214132/listings-use-different-style-for-normal-comments-and-doxygen-comments)
I used `listings` package to set style for `/** Doxygen comments */` as user defined delimiter

```
moredelim = [s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/}
```

This own delimiter should contain its own "keywords" that should not be messed with processed language keywords. Such "keywords" could be Doxygen's annotations for C++ code:

- C++ keywords should not be highlighted inside Doxygen delimiter `/** */`,
  /** **@author** int */
- Doxygen "keywords" should not be highlighted outside Doxygen delimiter
  @author **int**

File test.tex tests also strings, comments, other own delimiter.

```
\begin{MyCode}
/**
 * @author HERE
 * @param HERE
 * @return HERE
 * int float void not_here
 */
int main(void) {
  float f = @param + @return + not_here;
  string s = "@param @return not here";
  int @author = not_here;
  return 0;
}
#pragma not here @param @return
/* @author @param not here */
\end{MyCode}
```

Using `literate` highlights annotations **everywhere**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
literate={@param}{\bfseries @param}1
    {@return}{\bfseries @return}1
    {@author}{\bfseries @author}1,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{magenta},
commentstyle=\color{olive},
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/},
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma},
frame=single,showstringspaces = false,columns=flexible}
}{}

\begin{document}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

For some unknown reason it also removes spaces but it's not the main problem.

[image: Literate for Doxygen annotations]

The similar problem may appear if we want highlight something else inside pragma delimiter

```
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma},
```

or inside normal strings and comments.

Answer (score 3):

My second solution is not exactly what I wanted.

I should find whether I'm inside my moredelim or not.
Instead I check the font properties specific for that moredelim.

## Test against font family

1. I make Doxygen comment the only style which uses `\sffamily`

   moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}\sffamily]{/**}{*/}, %doxygen comment
2. Inside `literate` rule I use a conditional against `\sffamily`

#### Complete example

doc.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyBoldSf}[1]{%
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{\sfdefault}=\z@%
{\color{green!30!black}\bfseries #1 }%extra space
\else%
#1 %extra space
\fi%
}%
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
literate={@param}{\MyBoldSf{@param}}1
   {@return}{\MyBoldSf{@return}}1
   {@author}{\MyBoldSf{@author}}1,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
%identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{magenta},
commentstyle=\color{olive},
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}\sffamily]{/**}{*/}, %doxygen comment
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma}, %preprocessor
frame=single,showstringspaces = false,columns=flexible}
}{}

\begin{document}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

test.tex

```
\begin{MyCode}
/**
 * @author HERE
 * @param HERE
 * @return HERE
 * int float void not_here
 */
int main(void) {
  float f = @param + @return + not_here;
  string s = "@param @return not here";
  int @author = not_here;
  return 0;
}
#pragma not here @param @return
/*@author @param not here  */
\end{MyCode}
```

[image]

#### Problems

1. I didn't want to have Doxygen Comments as `\sffamily`. I want them to remain `\ttfamily` like the rest of code. I would rather test against moredelim or unique property like font color (ForestGreen in the example)
2. I still have problems with extra spaces. With the above solution I get extra space inside normal comment or a string. If i remove space from the solution, I get no space when command `\MyBoldSf` is used.

## Test against font color

I've asked a question about [conditional against font color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245409/conditional-against-font-color). According to given answers I have written command to change test with specific color

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyChange}[2]{%
  \extractcolorspec{.}\MyChange@CurrentColor
  \extractcolorspec{#2}\MyChange@TestColor
  \ifx\MyChange@CurrentColor\MyChange@TestColor
    {\bfseries\color{green!33!black} #1 }%
  \else
    {#1 }%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
literate={@param}{\MyChange{@param}{ForestGreen}}1
   {@return}{\MyChange{@return}{ForestGreen}}1
   {@author}{\MyChange{@author}{ForestGreen}}1,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{magenta},
commentstyle=\color{olive},
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/}, %doxygen comment
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma}, %preprocessor
frame=single,showstringspaces = false,columns=flexible}
}{}

\begin{document}
\input{test2}
\end{document}
```

Where  test2.tex is

```
\begin{MyCode}
/**
 * @author BOLD HERE
 * @param BOLD HERE
 * @return BOLD HERE
 * int float void not_here
 */
int main(void) {
  float f = @param + @return + here_not_bold;
  string s = "@param @return here not bold";
  int @author = here_not_bold;
  return 0;
}
#pragma not here @param @return
/*@author @param not here  */
#pragma omp parallel private(id)
\end{MyCode}
```

[image]

## Test against font color (more general)

Command `MyChange` can be used for replacing words within different colors

For example, there could be added special words for #pragma delim

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyChange}[3]{%
  \extractcolorspec{.}\MyChange@CurrentColor
  \extractcolorspec{#2}\MyChange@TestColor
  \ifx\MyChange@CurrentColor\MyChange@TestColor
    {\bfseries\color{#3} #1}%
  \else
    {#1}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
literate={@param}{\MyChange{@param}{ForestGreen}{green!33!black} }1
   {@return}{\MyChange{@return}{ForestGreen}{green!33!black} }1
   {@author}{\MyChange{@author}{ForestGreen}{green!33!black} }1
   {omp}{\MyChange{omp}{red}{red!66!black} }1
   {parallel}{\MyChange{parallel}{red}{red!66!black} }1
   {private}{\MyChange{private}{red}{red!66!black} }1,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{magenta},
commentstyle=\color{olive},
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/}, %doxygen comment
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma}, %preprocessor
frame=single,showstringspaces = false,columns=flexible}
}{}

\begin{document}
\input{test2}
\end{document}
```

For the same test2.tex I get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My first solution for formatting Annotation inside Doxygen is not autamatic.
It requires manual edition of source code.

While defining `MyCode` I set `escapechar` to enable formatting of the desired words

```
\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
escapechar=~,
...
}{}
```

Inside `MyCode` pasted source is manually extended with formatting

```
\begin{MyCode}
~\bfseries{}\ttfamily{}@param~ 
\end{MyCode}
```

### Complete example

Main document `doc.tex` contains definition of the command `\DoxAnno` which will be used for highlighting

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\DoxAnno}[1]{\ttfamily{\bfseries{\textcolor{green!33!black}{#1}}}} %Doxygen Annotation

\lstnewenvironment{MyCode}
{\lstset{language=C++,
escapechar=~,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{magenta},
commentstyle=\color{olive},
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/**}{*/}, %doxygen comment
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{\#pragma}, %preprocessor
frame=single,showstringspaces = false,columns=flexible}
}{}

\begin{document}
\input{testEscape}
\end{document}
```

testEscape.tex

```
\begin{MyCode}
/**
 * ~\DoxAnno{@author}~ HERE
 * ~\DoxAnno{@param}~ HERE
 * ~\DoxAnno{@return}~ HERE
 * int float void not_here
 */
int main(void) {
  float f = @param + @return + not_here;
  string s = "@param @return not here";
  int @author = not_here;
  return 0;
}
#pragma not here @param @return
/* @author @param not here */
\end{MyCode}
```

[image]